# Как сделать красивый HTTP_USER_AGENT?

Tags: php

Как сделать красивый `HTTP_USER_AGENT`?

Например `<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; ?>` дает нам такую информациЮ:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.52 Safari/537.36 OPR/31.0.1889.50 (Edition beta)`.

Как сделать, чтоб было просто `Mozilla 32.5 Windows 7` или `Opera 33 Windows 8.1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция `get-browser`

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";

$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
?>
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [parent] => Firefox 0.9
    [platform] => WinXP
    [browser] => Firefox
)
```

[Замечание](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.get-browser.php):
Для работы этой функции необходимо, чтобы в установке browscap в настройках php.ini был установлен корректный путь к файлу browscap.ini в вашей системе.
browscap.ini не поставляется с PHP, но вы можете последнюю его версию здесь: » php_browscap.ini.
browscap.ini содержит информацию о большинстве браузеров, он требует обновлений для поддержания его базы актуальной Формат файла довольно очевиден.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию! А можно сделать парсинг `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];` ?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под парсингом?

Comment: Просто, ладно спасибо все работает!

Answer (score 0):

Смотри в сторону [get_browser()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.get-browser.php)

или пиши свой разбор строки

Comment: Попробовал чета не получается `get_browser()`. Дает такой ошибка `Warning: get_browser() [function.get-browser]: browscap ini directive not set in`

Comment: Ее подключить нужно в php.ini, указав путь к browsercap.ini, который нужно предварительно скачать. По моей ссылке справка по функции и ссылка на файл ini, который содержит информацию по каждому UserAgent.

Comment: Дмитрий спасибо!